# PHP PayPal - Create an Invoice Integration

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to submit a paypal invoice to a customer after a certain amount of time has been tracked.
How do I convert the curl request located https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/invoicing/integration-guide/InvoiceAPIExamples
to a php function?

Comment: **What have you tried?** We're not here to convert _x_ into _y_ for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [PHP library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/) has this already done for you. All you have to do is open up the CreateAndSendInvoice.php file and fill in the request parameters accordingly.